# regex as a separator to read tables in python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to ask some help to read a text file (Python 2.7, pandas library) that is using "|" as a separator, but you can also find the same character in the records followed by space.  The first two rows don't have the problem, but the third one has the separator in between the 6th field **TAT Fans | Southern**

```
1. 4_230_0415_99312||||9500|Gedung|||||||||15000|6.11403|102.23061
2. 4_230_0415_99313||||9500|Pakatan|||||||||50450|3.15908|101.71431
3. 4_230_0117_12377||||9990|TAT Fans | Southern||||||||||3.141033333|101.727125
```

I have been trying to use regex in the separator, but I haven't been able to make it work :

```
pd.read_table("text_file.txt", sep = "\S+\|\S+")
```

Can Anyone help me find a solution to my problem?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using small `s`. Also what's the issue you're facing?

Comment: And you don't need to escape `|` I think.

Comment: Is this not enough?  `\s?[|]+\s` or \s?\|+\s?

Comment: Hello Rahul, my issue here is that the string  "TAT Fans | Southern"  is one record and I need to keep the "|" in the string, I don't want to loose it. The "|" (pipe)  between those two words with spaces is part of the record. If I use your approach, I will loos it  and the record will be divided. I need a regex that can only  use any pipe that is not followed or preceded by a space as a separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `"\s?[|]+\s?"`

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_table("text_file.txt", sep="\s?[|]+\s?") #or "\s?\|+\s?"

Out[18]:

   4_230_0415_99312  9500    Gedung     15000   6.11403   102.23061
0  4_230_0415_99313  9500   Pakatan     50450  3.159080  101.714310
1  4_230_0117_12377  9990  TAT Fans  Southern  3.141033  101.727125
```